# svmtrain data input order in matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, training-data

I'd like to know whether the order of train data for svmtrain in matlab is important and affects the classifier performance or not.
e.g I have two classes, labeled as 0 and 1. The train data array first 500 elements are from class 0 and the rest are from class 1. Will it perform better if data from two classes in train data array are in random order?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not depends on the order of the data but it depends on the number of training samples. If you want to experiment, you may try with different `method` and `kernel_function`.